# How to get characteristicUuid?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

I use **RxAndroidBle** https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle library to work with ble device. But I have a problem with finding **characteristicUuid**.

I do all from README, but can't find characteristicUuid. In read() need to execute `.flatMapSingle { rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(characteristicUuid) }`, but there is no **characteristicUuid**. Where I can get it?

```
private lateinit var rxBleClient: RxBleClient
    private lateinit var bleDevice: RxBleDevice
    private lateinit var characteristicUuid: UUID

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    getLocationPermission()

    rxBleClient = RxBleClient.create(this)

    val enableBtIntent = Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE)
    startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT)

    button.setOnClickListener { discover() }
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    }
}

private lateinit var scanSubscription: Disposable

private fun discover() {
    Log.i("BLE", "start scan")
    scanSubscription = rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(
        ScanSettings.Builder()
            // .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY) // change if needed
            // .setCallbackType(ScanSettings.CALLBACK_TYPE_ALL_MATCHES) // change if needed
            .build()
        // add filters if needed
    )
        .subscribe(
            { scanResult ->
                bleDevice = scanResult.bleDevice
                Log.i("BLE", "SCAN ${bleDevice.name} ${bleDevice.macAddress}")
                connect()
                scanSubscription.dispose()
                // Process scan result here.
            },
            { throwable ->
                Log.i("BLE", "ERROR SCAN ${throwable.localizedMessage}")
                // Handle an error here.
            }
        )

}

private lateinit var connectDisposable: Disposable

private fun connect() {
    val device = bleDevice

    connectDisposable = device.establishConnection(false) // <-- autoConnect flag
        .subscribe(
            { rxBleConnection ->
                Log.i("BLE", "CONNECT ${rxBleConnection.mtu}")
                read(device)
                connectDisposable.dispose()
                // All GATT operations are done through the rxBleConnection.
            },
            { throwable ->
                Log.i("BLE", "ERROR CONNECT ${throwable.localizedMessage}")
                // Handle an error here.
            }
        )

}

private fun read(device: RxBleDevice) {
    val dis = device.establishConnection(false)
        .flatMapSingle { rxBleConnection -> rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(characteristicUuid) }
        .subscribe(
            { characteristicValue ->
                Log.i("BLE", "READ $characteristicValue")
                // Read characteristic value.
            },
            { throwable ->
                Log.i("BLE", "ERROR READ ${throwable.localizedMessage}")
                // Handle an error here.
            }
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Characteristic's UUID probably should be mentioned in the manufacturer's manual/info about the bluetooth device you are using.
From my experience, our team had an engeneer, who provided us with documentation about device's ble services&characteristics and their UUIDs.

You can get all the ble services, characteristics and their UUIDs in your device with below code

```
rxBleConnection.discoverServices()
   .map(rxBleDeviceServices -> {
      List<BluetoothGattService> services = rxBleDeviceServices.getBluetoothGattServices();

      for (BluetoothGattService service : services) {
         // here you can work with service's uuid
         String serviceUuid = service.getUuid().toString();

         // or with all characteristics in service
         List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> characteristics = service.getCharacteristics();

         for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic : characteristics) {
            // here you have your characteristic's UUID
            String characteristicUuid = characteristic.getUuid().toString();
         }
   });
```

Then you save one of the BluetoothGattCharacteristic or UUID you have found and pass it to `rxBleConnection.readCharacteristic(bluetoothGattCharacteristic)`

Comment: Okey, but I have another problem in `read()` have an exception _Already connected to device with MAC address FF:FF:C3:0A:62:F3_

Comment: Well, you make ```establishConnection``` call twice. Thats why you get your exception.
You have to pass ```RxBleConnection``` to method ```read``` and not ```RxBleDevice``` since you already have a valid connection

Comment: Have another exception **service.getCharacteristic(characteristicUuid) must not be null**

Comment: or if I put characteristicUuid **Characteristic not found with UUID 00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb**

Comment: Are you sure, characteristic with this UUID exists in your device? Have you found it in manufacturer's info? I guess, I need more logs to make more detailed answer

Comment: I think I solved this problem. I have next code to read, but when I push buttons on BLE device there is no result 
`.subscribe({ characteristicValue ->
 characteristicValue
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe { t1, t2 ->
       Log.i("BLE", "READ T $t1")
        if (t2 != null) {Log.i("BLE", "READ T ${t2.localizedMessage}")}
      }
    },
    { throwable ->
      Log.i("BLE", "ERROR READ ${throwable.localizedMessage}") })`

Comment: If you want to be notified in code whenever you press a button, you have to set up notification via ```rxBleConnection.setupNotification(characteristic)```

Comment: I try, but no result

Comment: Have you tried to scan and connect to your device through other apps, for example, LightBlue, to make sure your device has accessible characteristics and permissions to read/write?

Comment: Well, I'm a little bit confused. If you want, you can contact me, for instance, via Telegram for more detailed info

Comment: Good, write me @dmeln

Comment: Can you provide a Kotlin implementation, since the original question was written in Kotlin? Also, ``rxBleDeviceServices `` doesn't exist.

Comment: Looks very impolite to downvote my answer, as it completely solves Dmytro's question. Additionally, I cannot take into account the phrase "rxBleDeviceServices doesn't exist" without any proof.